# Datastax DSE 5.0 Graph: Gremlin console not working

Tags: datastax-enterprise, gremlin, tinkerpop, datastax-enterprise-graph

I have installed DSE 5.0 on a cloud-based server to try out the Gremlin tools.  DSE in general seems to be OK, with the relevant ports available etc, but when I start Gremlin console on the server command-line, the console opens OK, but the basic first steps in simply creating a graph from the tutorials raise errors:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]

gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph cannot be cast to com.datastax.bdp.graph.api.DseGraphInternal
Display stack trace? [yN] y
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.plugin.RemoteException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph cannot be cast to com.datastax.bdp.graph.api.DseGraphInternal
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.groovy.plugin.DriverRemoteAcceptor.submit(DriverRemoteAcceptor.java:170)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy:90)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:122)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:95)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1212)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:152)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:124)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1212)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:152)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:83)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:228)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:174)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:228)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:361)
```

I also insalled DSE 5.0 on my local machine. Agan, DSE Cassandra seems to work OK,  ut when I try to start the Gremlin console I get different errors:

```
dse gremlin-console

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.hasCustomStaticInvokeMethod()Z
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Selector$MethodSelector.chooseMeta(Selector.java:553)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Selector$MethodSelector.setCallSiteTarget(Selector.java:954)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:224)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<clinit>(Console.groovy:54)
```

I can't find much documentation around DSE 5.0 Graph, and nothing at all on dealing with errors like this.  Any tips would be very welcome.

Comment: You need to create an alias first. Look at the quick start guide to the gremlin console in the DataStax docs

Comment: Thanks!  That solves the errors inside the Gremlin console on my cloud-based installation.  The tutorial is here:  https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/QuickStartGremlin.html

Comment: Still don't know why I can't start the Gremlin console on my ,local installation though.

Comment: Should be the same